# SQLite INSERT SELECT Query Results into Existing Table?

Tags: sqlite

I've not used SQLite before but I'm muddling my way through it. I need to Insert the results from a select query into a existing table, but even after some lengthy web reading I'm still failing to complete this simple task. I'm using SQLite Studio to manage my database, their web site suggests a method of doing this, but it doesn't appear to work as SQLite Studio will throw up "near "INSERT": syntax errors. Could some one please help me or point me in the direction of the correct syntax for this please.

Comment: Can you add your current sql statement that's not working?  Are you just trying the raw sql or are you also using some API like the C api etc...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Reference](http://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).

The correct syntax is:

```
insert into table_name select whatever...
```

Comment: Thank your for your help, I found out I was been a bit simple by trying to run my insert query as a View which is a no no. I ended up creating a sql file containing my query and executing it from the cli when needed. Thank you for your time. :0)