# Most efficient way to duplicate a row in Sqlite for iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

What is the most efficient way to duplicate a row in an Sqlite3 database exactly except with an updated PrimaryKey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `insert .. select` where both the insert and select reference the same relation. Then the entire operation will occur as a single statement within SQLite code itself which cannot be beaten for "efficiency".

It will be easier with an auto-PK (just don't select the PK column), although an appropriate natural key can be assigned as well if such can be derived.

See [SQLite INSERT SELECT Query Results into Existing Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387338/sqlite-insert-select-query-results-into-existing-table)

Comment: I've used the code below but what I mean by effecient is the easiest way to select everything except for the PK without iterating the fields.

[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO mySets SELECT * FROM mySets WHERE setID='%d'", currentSet];

Comment: This approach *requires* that the PK field (and thus `*` is not appropriate) is omitted with auto-PKs. While this can be done by hand for a fixed/static relation shape, the columns selected will need to be built in some form - perhaps from a helper function than iterates the columns in the schema.

Comment: @user1440367 Whoops, I was wrong and [the auto-increment field can be supplied with a NULL value](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1) - however, it still requires a non-`*` approach to either omit the field or explicitly select NULL in.